# SSH File Pull from Remote Host Initialized Locally

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I am using a python script to launch remote linux commands from my local machine.  The target(s) is/are a list of server(s).  I am able to launch the commands no problem; however, the commands result in log files on the target.  I would like to pull down these log files to my local machine after they are written (pull them down programmatically).

Is there a way I can "PULL" a file down from a remote machine via a secure connection in such a way that the transfer is initialized locally?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Scp is included with openssh. If you need to transfer multiple files you can also use rsync -e ssh

Comment: `scp` also supports transferring of multiple files. It even supports recursive directory transfers.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp remote.host:/path/to/file /some/local/path
```

Or use `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for scp and rsync is always:

```
scp <source> <destination>
```

So it doesn't really matter which machine you do it from, the remote machine can either be the source or the destination.  You do however,  at least with rsync -e ssh, have to be on one of the two machines.